# Biasing regression by repeating variables

Tags: regression, biostatistics

I'm building linear discrimination analyses and logistic regressions and I am trying to bias the regressions to favor specific variables. Each variable represents chemical information from a specific geneID. Since the pool of geneIDs is large I have to group the genes together based on biological activity pathways and direction of correlation. Chemical information is averaged together within one group. I was wondering if it was ok to duplicate chemical information for a geneID that is relevant to multiple biological pathways. In the same respect, if the direction of correlation is reversed is it ok to switch the sign of the chemical information to make the direction of correlation match the biological group.

Ex:

```
AR - reproductive organ development - spermatogenesis- positive correlation

biological groups:
reproductive organ development- positive correlation
spermatogenesis- negative correlation
```

Would AR chemical info have to go in the group it is most related to, or could it go in both? Biological I would want to bias the output like that to stress the importance of AR in this pathway, but is it mathematically sound?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what biasing a regression model means here and why you want to achieve it. Statisticians advocate for unbiased estimates, consistent at least if biased estimates are unavoidable. In logistic regression, estimates (of coefficients) are at best consistent asymptotically.

If the number of predictors are large, variable selection, dimension reduction, and regularization are three typical methods to reach convergence.

- Variable selection includes stepwise (e.g. `step()`), best subset, genetic algorithm (e.g. `glmulti()`), and some other approaches that remove unimportant variables and retain important ones.
- A popular dimension reduction technique is principal component analysis (PCA) that decompose variable variation among several principal components, which seems to  fit the current needs of representing genes in multiple activity pathways. It is unclear how chemical information is represented, but averaging enforces equal weights among genes, which is more rigid than what PCA allows.
- Regularization is another technique for problems of many predictors with few observations common in gene studies that penalize large estimates. In practice, it includes LASSO, ridge, and elastic net. For logistic regression, all can achieved by `glmnet()`. If the response variable is ordinal instead of binary, ordinal regression allows many more predictors that can possibly exceed the number of observations.

I have not used linear discrimination analyses in practice, but I believe it achieves the same objective as logistic regression in estimating probabilities of two or more categories. Others can elaborate whether it is beneficial to conduct linear discrimination analysis in addition to logistic regression.